# Finite Field Theory Doubt: Ramakrishnan's Fourier Analysis on Number Fields, Section 4.2

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

My question refers to Ramakrishnan's Fourier Analysis On Number Fields, Chapter 4.2., Section "Roots of Unity in $k$", pg. 148-149.

Herein, we have that $k$ is an ultrametric space of characteristic $p$, with absolute value $|\cdot|$ and that $A \subset k$ is such that $A = \{x \in k: |x| \leq 1\}; P = \{x \in k: |x| < 1 \}$.

We have that $A/P$ is a finite field with $q = p^r$ elements, for some prime $p$. Now, for some $a \in A^*$ (the units of $A$), we have that eventually (for all sufficiently large n), $(a-1)^{q^n} = a^{q^n}-1 \in P$, where the equality comes because $A \subset k$, where $k$ is a field of characteristic $p$.

Ramakrishnan writes that this implies that $a \equiv 1$  $mod P$. I know that there is some finite field theory underlying this claim, but I am unable to fully explicate it. Could someone help justify this please?

Answer (score 1):

The only $p$-power root of unity in a field of characteristic $p$ (like $A/P$) is $1$ itself. Since it has been shown that the residue of $a$ modulo $P$ is such a root of unity, the claim follows.